# delete ids from subquery results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-delete, delete-row

Lets say I have this `users` table:

```
id email
1  test@gmail.com
2  xxp@gmail.com
3  test@gmail.com
4  zzz@gmail.com
```

And I want to delete rows that have duplicated `emails`.

First I thought of retrieving duplicated emails:

```
select id
group by email
having count(*)>1
```

Which results in:

**updated result**

```
1
```

Then I added the `delete` clause:

```
delete from users
where id in(
    select id
    group by email
    having count(*)>1 )
```

The result is No Errors, but 0 rows affected... which means nothing happened.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong and some other ways of doing this.

Specifications: MySQL 5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB
Using Sequel Pro on Mac

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a sub-query to get the id or ids having duplicate then remove it from your table.  See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f14d05/1

```
DELETE from users 
where id in (
     SELECT id 
     from (
           SELECT a.id, count(*) as rn 
             FROM users a
            JOIN users b ON a.email = b.email AND a.id <= b.id
           GROUP BY a.id, a.email
          )  t
      where rn>1
      );
```

Comment: concept is good but it erases every row with same email, doesn't leave one at users table

Comment: you changed the requirements; earlier it shows delete id=1,3. Will update my answer soon

Comment: yes, sorry, I realized that wasn't the result and forgot to update

Comment: i updated my answer based on the new requirements. Thanks.

Comment: not working, it shows no error but 0 files are affected

Comment: do you see the demo in sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f14d05/1.  It shows the duplicate emails are removed.

Comment: do this in your database and show me the result.  Select count(*) as cnt, email from users group by email order by cnt desc limit 10.  this will give you top 10 duplicate emails.

Comment: thanks, I was doing something wrong...it really works

Answer (score 0):

Tested on MSSQL.

```
select min(id) id, email 
into #users 
from [users]
group by email

delete from [users] where id not in (select id from #users)

drop table #users
```